# PostgreSQL trigger procedure to change an INSERT field value based on different table's field

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, constraints, postgresql-9.3

I have a table named cases with the following fields:

- caseid (primary key)
- casenumber
- dateoffiling etc.

among other fields.

In another table, invoices, I refer the caseid as a foriegn key such as

- invoiceid (primary key)
- invoicecode
- caseid (foriegn key -> cases.caseid)
- invoicedate
  etc.

Now whenever I insert a record into invoices, I want to check that invoicedate is greater than or equal to cases.dateoffiling (for that particular invoice) and if not, I want to either trigger an exception or set invoicedate equal to dateoffiling (you cannot raise an invoice before filing a case).

I've tried to break my head with Postgresql pgsql triggers including documentation and examples, but I wasn't able to find the aforesaid scenario anywhere. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the solution for the trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION invoicedatecheck()
   RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$declare 
    filingdate date;
begin
    select dateoffiling from cases where casesid=new.caseid into filingdate;

    if new.invoicedate < filingdate then
    new.invoicedate = filingdate;
    end if;
    return new;
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION invoicedatecheck()
OWNER TO remoteuser;
```